# jQuery - Wait for variable to update before triggering alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a very basic question, but I can't seem to find the right answer. How can I wait for the variables to be updated before triggering the alert? I read I'm suppose to use a callback, but there are two functions so I'm not sure how to use callback when I have one "global" alert.

Right now the alert gets triggered empty because the variable isn't updated.

```
  var WaardeStrafblad = ""
     var WaardeVerzekering = ""

     $('input:checkbox[id=Strafblad]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Strafblad").is(":checked")) {

            WaardeStrafblad = "Ik heb geen strafblad"

            } else {

            WaardeStrafblad = ""

            }

        });

         $('input:checkbox[id=Verzekering]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Verzekering").is(":checked")) {

            WaardeVerzekering = "Ik ben bereid een verzekering af te sluiten"

            } else {

            WaardeVerzekering = ""

            }

        });

$("#Strafblad").click(function(){
    alert(WaardeStrafblad + " " + WaardeVerzekering);
});
```

Comment: so add a check that they have values before alerting....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things here. First off, it's better to use less complex jQuery selectors, especially if your elements have `id` attributes. It's faster and less prone to making mistakes so I would change the code like this:

```
var WaardeStrafblad = "";
var WaardeVerzekering = "";

$("#Strafblad").change(function() {
  if ($("#Strafblad").is(":checked")) {
    WaardeStrafblad = "Ik heb geen strafblad";
  } else {
    WaardeStrafblad = "";
  }
});

$("#Verzekering").change(function() {
  if ($("#Verzekering").is(":checked")) {
    WaardeVerzekering = "Ik ben bereid een verzekering af te sluiten";
  } else {
    WaardeVerzekering = "";
  }
});

$("#Strafblad").click(function() {
  alert(WaardeStrafblad + " " + WaardeVerzekering);
});
```

Notice how we no longer check for `input:checkbox`, if we already know the `id` there's no need to specify that it's an `input` of type `checkbox`.

The reason this fails is that the change listener fires after the click listener, so it will only print as expected if you click the `Strafblad` checkbox AFTER you've checked `Verzekering` (or if it's your second click on `Strafblad`).

Since the click listener will also fire on change, simply get rid of that listener and add the alert call to the end of the change listener for `Strafblad` like so:

```
var WaardeStrafblad = "";
var WaardeVerzekering = "";

$("#Strafblad").change(function() {
  if ($("#Strafblad").is(":checked")) {
    WaardeStrafblad = "Ik heb geen strafblad";
  } else {
    WaardeStrafblad = "";
  }
  alert(WaardeStrafblad + " " + WaardeVerzekering);
});

$("#Verzekering").change(function() {
  if ($("#Verzekering").is(":checked")) {
    WaardeVerzekering = "Ik ben bereid een verzekering af te sluiten";
  } else {
    WaardeVerzekering = "";
  }
});
```

Perhaps it should also go at the end of the other listener but unfortunately I don't understand the language so I will just give you a minimal solution :)

[Here is a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRdvjP)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive explanation. Learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You must store the elements into a variable.
Next you create a function to check each element is filled.

your code should be:

```js
// this order of the object define the output order
var Waarde = {
   Strafblad: "",
   Verzekering: ""
 };

 var elements = $('#Strafblad, #Verzekering');

 elements.change(function() {

   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     Waarde[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();

     if (checkforFilledObject(Waarde)) {
       alert(outputElements(Waarde));
     }
   } else {
     Waarde[$(this).attr('id')] = "";
   }

   console.log(Waarde);
 });

 function checkforFilledObject(values) {
   var filled = true;
   $.each(values, function(i, value) {
     if (value === "") {
       filled = false;
     }
   });

   return filled;
 }

 function outputElements(values) {
   var valueArrays = Object.keys(values).map(function(key) {
     return values[key];
   });
   return valueArrays.join(' ');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Strafblad" value="Ik heb geen strafblad"> Strafblad 
<input type="checkbox" id="Verzekering" value="Ik ben bereid een verzekering af te sluiten"> Strafblad
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of approaches you could do there. You could include the `click` event registration in an `if/then` that runs after the checkboxes have been checked.

But, in this case, I think it's simpler to just wrap the `alert` in an `if/then` that test for the two variables and doesn't show the `alert` unless they've both been initialized:

```js
    var WaardeStrafblad = ""
    var WaardeVerzekering = ""

    $('input:checkbox[id=Strafblad]').change(function () {
      if ($("#Strafblad").is(":checked")) {
        WaardeStrafblad = "Ik heb geen strafblad"
      } else {
        WaardeStrafblad = ""
      }

    });

    $('input:checkbox[id=Verzekering]').change(function () {
      if ($("#Verzekering").is(":checked")) {
        WaardeVerzekering = "Ik ben bereid een verzekering af te sluiten"
      } else {
        WaardeVerzekering = ""
      }

    });

    $("#Strafblad").click(function(){
      // Just check that both variables are not empty
      if(WaardeStrafblad  && WaardeVerzekering ){
        alert(WaardeStrafblad + " " + WaardeVerzekering);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Strafblad"> Strafblad 
<input type="checkbox" id="Verzekering"> Strafblad
```

Comment: the if logic in the click function is not useful as the default values are already given as empty strings. Before the value gets updated the if condition returns false and nothing will display

Comment: @praveen You are completely misunderstanding the question and the solution. In my code, if you click `#Strafblad`, it will check to see if both `WaardeStrafblad` and `WaardeVerzekering` have "truthy" values (values that are **not** `empty`, `0`, `null` or `undefined`). If the user has not checked the checkboxes then both variables will still have their default values of `""`, which is "falsey" and therefore, no `alert()` will be shown. But, when both variables do have values (they are both "truthy", which is what my `if` condition tests for), the `alert` will be shown. This is JavaScript 101.

Comment: @praveen And, just so you can get your head around this, I've made this code a snippet so you can run it and see it work. Then, you can retract your down vote.

Answer (score -2):

can use timeout function and delay the execution of click function

```
$("#Strafblad").click(function(){
    setTimeout(" alert(WaardeStrafblad + " " + WaardeVerzekering);", 2000);   
});
```

or you can just trigger the cick inside change at the end.

Comment: So, what if the user hasn't clicked any checkboxes after 2 seconds

Comment: Why would the user have to wait 2 seconds? Who knows, they might have clicked a second time already. Also, it is bad practice to let JavaScript evaluate code like that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  why should user click after 2 seconds.. this is setting a timeout to show alert after used had already clicked.

Comment: You need to rethink your own logic and re-read my comment. I didn't say the user would click after 2 seconds. All your code does is wait two seconds before showing nothing when neither checkbox has been checked.

Comment: @ScottMarcus when neighter checkbox is checked, this click function won't be executed.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would prevent this click function from running if neither checkbox is checked. Please stop arguing this point. Your logic and code is wrong. All this code does is delay the display of the `alert` by 2 seconds. If the variables haven't been set (by clicking the checkboxes), then the `alert` will show nothing.

Comment: Additionally, your code (as written) won't even run because your `setTimeout()` syntax is wrong. But, to see what your own code does, go here: https://jsfiddle.net/gL79m7t7/5/ and click the first checkbox only, then wait 2 seconds.